# closing dialog window without selecting any value from dialog I am getting error angular

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular8

When I close the dialog without selecting any value from the dialog window I am getting following error.

```
core.js:4002 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'CTMSInstitutionName' of null

      openDialog(element, i): void {
        if(!this.allMatch){

        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogCTMSComponent, {
          disableClose: true,
          data: { cTMSTableDisplay: this.ctmsDisplay, title: element.ibtInstitutionName + ' / ' + element.ibtInvestigatorFullName, result: this.dataService.matchSiteResult }
        });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          if(this.dataService.matchSiteResult.CTMSInstitutionName > 0){
            this.ctmsValueArray[i].CTMSInstitutionName = this.dataService.matchSiteResult.CTMSInstitutionName;
            this.ctmsValueArray[i].CTMSInvestigatorName = this.dataService.matchSiteResult.CTMSInvestigatorName;
            this.ctmsValueArray[i].SiteNumber = this.dataService.matchSiteResult.SiteNumber;
            this.ctmsValueArray[i].StatusFlag = "M";
            this.countryTableDisplay.data[i].siteNumber = this.dataService.matchSiteResult.SiteNumber;
          }

          this.payloadarray.push(this.ctmsValueArray[i]);
          let founndindex = this.ctmsDisplay.findIndex(item => { return (item.ctmsInstitutionName == this.dataService.matchSiteResult.CTMSInstitutionName)});
          if(founndindex >= 0){
            this.ctmsDisplay.splice(founndindex, 1);
          }

          if(this.ctmsDisplay.length == 0){
            this.allMatch = true; 
          }

        });

      }
      }
```

Please let me know how to handle this error.

Comment: Maybe the problem is on `DialogCTMSComponent` when you are closing the dialog.

Comment: what is the problem will be there.... the above code only  I am handling

Comment: When you are closing the dialog it must be returning something. please debug in `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { })`

Comment: try to console.log each time 'CTMSInstitutionName' is used as you are trying to access the CTMSInstitutionName  property of an null object. It will help you to find where the null object is located.

Comment: @Mridul while I am debugging I am getting undefined at the initial line itself 

if(this.dataService.matchSiteResult.CTMSInstitutionName) it's coming undefined in the initial if itself